# Apache Cordova -- Download file from local web directory to Android/iOS directories?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

having a bit of trouble with my download function for Cordova. I have a function here:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  var fileUrl = e.target.getAttribute('data-soundurl');
    console.log(fileUrl);
    //returns as "../www/card-sounds/sound2.m4a"
  var fileOutputPath = e.target.getAttribute('data-quote') + ".m4a";
    console.log(fileOutputPath);
    //returns as "Sound Title.m4a"

  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var output = "file:///android_asset/www/res/db/"+fileOutputPath;

  fileTransfer.download(
    fileUrl,
    output,
    function(entry) {console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());},
    function(error) {console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                     console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                     console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                    },
    false,
    {headers:{"Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="}}
  );
  console.log(output);
  //returns as "file:///android_asset_www_res/db/Sound Title.m4a"
}, true);
```

And my log output just shows:

```
download error source null
download error target null
upload error codenull
```

I can't seem to get any sort of .root part of the FileSystem to actually give me a defined string so I'm just trying to get it to download to Android for now. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I am so confused here.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, download function is to download from internet, and by the url you show, it seems you already have them in your www folder. If you already have the files on your www folder just read them

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

var output = "/res/db/"+fileOutputPath;

Answer (score 0):

For your output use

```
var output = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + fileOutputPath;
```

cordova.file.externalRootDirectory should give you something like "file:///storage/emulated/0/"